# asp forms with authentication over owin - Login failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, owin

I created a web application with asp webforms, ef 6.0 and authentication over owin. on dev system works everything perfect. I published the webapp on iis on windows server 2012. Login works fine, but suddenly after some time, the users are not able to authenticate. I need to make a recycle of the apppool and then its working again. then same again after some time not able to login. I have no excpetions or erros in the windows or app logs. Also the connection to the database is working because i get some user infos from database (tested it with inactive flag). web.config also looks okay. Formsauthentication is deactivated and modules removed.

I have a second webapp also with an owin authentication on same iis without any problems.

someone has a clue what can cause that problem?

thx
Ronald

Comment: What application? What code? I have no clue what you're talking about, and nobody will until you can show what you're doing. Please, give us enough code that we can understand the problem, or even better, reproduce the issue so we can confirm we've fixed it.

Comment: I will post some code tmr. I dont have it now with me. sorry.

Comment: Better to pull this question for now and re-post when you have code.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution.

After the authentication i made

Context.Redirect(url);

I needed to change to

Context.redirect(url, false);

For unclear reasons its possible that the Cookie is not created and added to the context before the redirect. Then asp has No Cookie and redirect again to Login.

Thx, ronald